# How to extract model grid cells from NetCDF file corresponding with specific latitudes and longitudes and show both on one graph?

Tags: r, csv, netcdf4

I have only been working with R for the past three weeks, so I am very much a novice.  I am currently working with NetCDF climate data from across New England(path).  I also have a .csv file with coordinates of specific cities we want to look at (cities.path).  I have been able to extract the time annual time series and trend from model grid cells corresponding to the specific cities from the .csv file.  The problem has been with being able to plot the important city stations from my .csv file onto the map with annual averages.

When I run the script line 
'ave_annual_cities <- extract(annual_ave_stack, cities.points, df = T)'
I get a latitude/longitude graph with my important cities points. When I run 'plot(coordinates(cities.points))' in the console, I again get a latitude/longitude graph with my important cities points, however it stands alone, separate from my ave_annual_cities graph. 
When I run 'levelplot(subset(annual_ave_stack, 1), margin=F) + 
  layer(sp.points(cities.points, plot.grid = TRUE))' I get a graph of New England with annual averages.

Here is my script so far.

```
#Coordinate CS lat/lon pull from Important City Stations
# imports the csv of lat/lon for specific cities
# reads the lat/lon of the .nc modeled climate files
# extracts the time annual time series and trend from model grid cells 
corresponding to your specific cities' locations.
#Graphs City points according to annual time series graph

# Libraries (probably do not need all)
library(survival)
library(lattice)
library(ncdf4)
library(RNetCDF)
library(date)
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(latticeExtra)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(wux)

path <- "/net/nfs/merrimack/raid/Northeast_US_Downscaling_cmip5/"
vars = c("tasmin","tasmax")
mods = c("ACCESS1-0", "ACCESS1-3",
     "bcc-csm1-1-m", "bcc-csm1-1")
scns = c("rcp45", "rcp85")

cities.path <-
"/net/home/cv/marina/Summer2017_Projects/Lat_Lon/NE_Important_Cities.csv"
necity.vars <- c("City", "State", "Population", "Latitude", "Longitude", 
"Elevation(meters")

#These both read the .csv file (first uses 'utils', second uses 'wux')
#1
cities.read <- read.delim(cities.path, header = T, sep = ",")
#2
read.table <- read.wux.table(cities.path)
cities.read <- subset(cities.read, subreg = "City", sep = ",")

# To test one coordinate point
point_1 <- c("test.city", 44.31, -69.79)
colnames(point_1)<-c("cities", "latitude", "longitude" )

# To read only "Cities", "Latitude", and "Longitude"
cities.points <- subset(cities.read, select = c(1, 4, 5))
cities.points <- as.data.frame(cities.points)
colnames(cities.points)<- c("City", "Latitude", "Longitude" )

#Set plot coordinates for .csv graph
coordinates(cities.points) <- ~ Longitude + Latitude
proj4string(cities.points) <- c("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 
+towgs84=0,0,0") 

# Start loop to envelope all .nc files
for (iv in 1:2){
  for (im in 1:4){
    for (is in 1:2){
      for(i in 2006:2007){
        full<-paste(path, vars[iv], "_day_", mods[im], "_", scns[is], 
"_r1i1p1_", i, "0101-", i, "1231.16th.nc", sep="")
    # this will print out 
    #/net/nfs/merrimack/raid/Northeast_US_Downscaling_cmip5/NameOfFiles.nc

    # this line will print the full file name
    print(full)

    # use the brick function to read the full netCDF file.
    # note: the varname argument is not necessary, but if a file has multiple 
varables, brick will read the first one by default.
    air_t<-brick(full, varname=vars[iv])

    # use the calc function to get an average for each grid cell over the 
entire year
    annual_ave_t<-calc(air_t, fun = mean, na.rm=T)

        if(i == 2006){
          annual_ave_stack = annual_ave_t
        }else{
          annual_ave_stack<-stack(annual_ave_stack, annual_ave_t)
        }  # end of if/else 
      }   # end of year loop
      #extract annual means for grid cells for each year corresponding to 
 important cities
  ave_annual_cities <- extract(annual_ave_stack, cities.points, df = T)
    }   # end of scenario loop
  }   # end of model loop
}  # end of variable loop


levelplot(subset(annual_ave_stack, 1), margin=F) + 
  layer(sp.points(cities.points, plot.grid = TRUE))

# Read lat/lon from .nc climate files
# http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog607/Rmd/netCDF_01.htm
climate.data <- nc_open(full)
lat <- ncvar_get(climate.data, varid = "lat")
nlat <- dim("lat")
lat
lon <- ncvar_get(climate.data, varid =  "lon")
nlon <- dim("lon")
lon
  # This gives all lat data. 

#print long and lat variables: confirms the dimensions of the data
print(c(nlon, nlat))


  # If I need time series... 
my.time <- nc_open(climate.data, "time")
n.dates <- trunc(length(climate.data))
n.dates

# open NetCDF choosing pop and lat/lon points
cities.pop.points <- subset(cities.read, select = c(1, 3, 4, 5))
# print NetCDF coordinates with pop
print(cities.pop.points)
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If your input data is correctly read as a multiband raster, you could read the netcdf as a raster using:

```
 r     <- raster::stack(path)
 cells <- raster::cellFromXY(r, xy)
 data  <- raster::extract(r, cells)
```

, where `xy` is a matrix of x/y coordinates you can get quite easily from your csv using
something on the lines of:

```
 as.matrix(csv_read(cities.path))
```

HTH

Comment: I am having trouble with the expressions : 
cells <- raster::cellFromXY(r, xy)
 data  <- raster::extract(r, cells)

I have changed the latitude and longitude headings in my csv file to x and y, and these expressions are still not working.  Where should they be placed within my script, and how should I assign values for x and y so that when I run these lines I will not get 
Error in raster::cellFromXY(r, xy) : object 'xy' not found
Error in raster::extract(r, cells) : object 'cells' not found

Comment: As the error message is telling you, it seems that `xy` is not defined, so I think you are not correctly reading it from the file. What instruction are you using ? As wrote above, it should be something like `xy = as.matrix(csv_read(cities.path))`

Comment: This is what I have in my script:                                                                      r <- raster::stack(full) xy <- as.matrix(read.csv(cities.path)) cells <- raster::cellFromXY(cities.path(r, xy)) data  <- raster::extract(r, cells)                                                                   and I am getting back an error that reads, "Error in inherits(xy, "SpatialPoints") : argument "xy" is missing, with no default"                                                  and another, "Error in raster::extract(r, cells) : object 'cells' not found" . thanks for the help.

Comment: can you try to execute only `xy <- as.matrix(read.csv(cities.path))` and see what you get in the `xy` variable ?

Comment: Thanks for being so patient. When I print out xy, it gives every cell value of my csv file in matrix form. Is this expected?

Comment: yes, that's what I expected. I see this problematic line in your code: `cells <- raster::cellFromXY(cities.path(r, xy))` . should be just `cells <- raster::cellFromXY(r, xy)`

Comment: hmmm. I am getting a new error message when I try to run this edited line. it reads, "> cells <- raster::cellFromXY(r, xy)
Error in .doCellFromXY(object@ncols, object@nrows, object@extent@xmin,  : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double]."

Comment: what do you get from `summary(r)` ?

Comment: I get a reading like this of every day of the year in 2099.                           X2099.01.01 X2099.01.02 X2099.01.03 X2099.01.04 X2099.01.05
Min.       262.1193    260.6483    265.0800    261.7262    260.6938
1st Qu.    269.9096    270.7285    271.0857    269.5374    271.0583

Comment: mmm... very difficult to help without seeing the data... Could you share the csv and one "band" of the nectdf (or a link to it ) ?

Comment: see above edits. Let me know if you still need a link to the csv. Thanks